# Eclipse Tomcat debug on start

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I have web application - use Spring + Tomcat. I need debug method that starts on Tomcat start.
There is the problem - debugger is blocked until Tomcat not started, but I can't allow finish start Tomcat - because this method invoked only on start. Is there a way to resolve?
Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean on start? You can put breakpoints in ServletContextListeners for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start tomcat using this command `catalina jpda start` and then connect via remote debugger from eclipse, after setting breakpoints where ever you need them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried SpringSource Tool Suite (STS) which is an eclipse based IDE ? It provides [Spring Insight](http://static.springsource.com/projects/tc-server/6.0/devedition/cinintro.html) which is of great help when working on Tomcat with Spring